# Form validation in Django: What to override or not?

Tags: python, django, forms

I do not yet fully understand the validation process of Forms in Django. I've read the documentation about it already, but I've still questions.

In the [Mozilla Django Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms) you can read this:

> Django provides numerous places where you can validate your data. The
>   easiest way to validate a single field is to override the method
>   `clean_<fieldname>()` for the field you want to check. So for example,
>   we can validate that entered renewal_date values are between now and 4
>   weeks by implementing `clean_renewal_date()` as shown below.

My question now:
If I create methods like **clean_field_name()** what do I override? In the quote above it says that you'll override this method. However, I could not find what exactly I do override.

In case I do override something, isn't it bad? Or are those methods **only** methods you can create by your own but do not exist by default?

Comment: say if you define a charfield named name then `def clean_name(self, name): # do things you want ; return name` func helps to do the validation process for that particular field. You can get the name, adjust it's value and then return it.

Comment: `isn't it bad` no its not. Overriding method is part of your customisation to libraries and frameworks.

Comment: What exactly do I override? Could not find anything.

Comment: You're not necessarily overriding it in that tutorial.  You're using that specific data in a function, with logic, to return new data to the form.  If the data is less than today, or greater than four weeks from now, the data returned is a `ValidationError` INSTEAD of `cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial is (partly) wrong - the `clean_YOURFIELDNAME` methods are not overrides as there's no default `clean_YOURFIELDNAME` method to be overridden. It's just that the form validation will look for those methods and *if they are defined* call them as part as the validation process.

For the implementation details, the simplest is to read the source:  https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L379